Computationally Efficient Implementation of Kalman Filter
I know there are many formulations of the Kalman Filter. A few I can name are:

Classical Covariance Form
Informational Filter Form
Square-Root Form or Factor Form

But somehow it's hard for me to find a summary of their pros and cons from the computational standpoint. I want to find the computationally cheapest solution.
In my use case, my state transition matrix is the identity (the $F$ matrix in wikipedia) and the state transition noise covariance $Q$ matrix has a nice principal component structural (I can just take the first dozens of eigenvalues to compress the covariance matrix).  My observation vector size is usually at least 1/3, sometimes more than the state vector. My $R$ (observation noise) is diagonal. We can assume $R,Q$ are constant for all practical purposes
But I'd like to hear more about this computation complexity topic in general. I am programming it on a regular PC. I am not using it for signal processing purposes per se, Just a form of statistical least square estimation.

Google search results few alternatives... have you checked those already? computationally efficient implementation of Kalman Filter

Would the recursive least squares filter suit your application?

If the number of your states is more than you observation, then the classical form is generally the most computationally efficient version.
If your observation is more than your states, the information filter is better since you invert a smaller matrix.
Square-root filter is for numerical stability, it's generally slower.
If your R is diagonal, you might want to consider using a sequential filter. Basically add one observation at a time. Then you avoid that cost of inverting S matrix (you are just taking a reciprocal of a scalar). But it won't help your big O complexity.
Multiplying a general matrix is $O(n^3)$ in all practical purposes (yes, i know there is a faster algorithm in theory but in practice we generally accept it's $O(n^3)$). You usually have to explain special matrix structure to go anything below that. For example, is your Q diagonal? is your H sparse? etc.

What I found to be the most efficient is described in the paper Kevin Tracy - A Square Root Kalman Filter Using Only QR Decompositions:

It is relatively easy to implement in MATLAB, Python or Julia.
Another option, I haven't tried is given in Computation Aware Kalman Filtering and Smoothing. It claims to drop the matrix calculations all together.
